# jquery loop with ajax request works perfectly with an alert included, without alert fails?

Tags: jquery

I have the below syntax which works 100% correctly and populates the corresponding checkboxes:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 30; i++) {     
$.post('get_sku_prices', {data: $('#product'+i).val()},function(result) {
    $('#price'+i).val(result);
    $('#adjustedprice'+i).val(result);
});
alert(i);
}
```

As mentioned working correctly. If I remove the alert and just have

```
for (var i = 1; i < 30; i++) {   
$.post('get_sku_prices', {data: $('#product'+i).val()},function(result) {
    $('#price'+i).val(result);
    $('#adjustedprice'+i).val(result);
});

}
```

The fields are not being populated without the alert, almost like the alert is forcing the page to refresh.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous. The fields ARE getting updated, you just aren't waiting long enough for the requests to finish. You also have a typical scoping issue in your for loop with the i var.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: i'd suggest looking at a few ajax tutorials. You're missing a fundamental part of how ajax works. http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/key-concepts/ primarly the *"A is for Asynchronous"* section.

Comment: Sending 30 requests like that seems a bit wrong... Can't you improve your backend to return 30 results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own scoping function, something like that:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
    (function (index) {
        $.post('get_sku_prices', {
            data: $('#product' + index).val()
        }, function (result) {
            $('#price' + index).val(result);
            $('#adjustedprice' + index).val(result);
        });
    })(i)
}
```

Comment: Champion. Thanks, works 100% correctly! what do you mean by scoping function? what does function index() do? Thanks again.

Comment: Any chance of commenting this to assist me, sorry know I am being cheeky, just need to make sure I understand it :-) Thanks again...

Comment: @Smudger You have to understand how scope/closure work in javascript. See there for example: http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/  In my answer's code, index is a parameter which reference 'i' variable coming from 'for' loop. As ajax requests are asynchronous by default, using a closure function, you are sure that your 'index' correspond to the correct value of 'i' at time of instantiation. Otherwise, without using closure (scoping) function, 'index' would get value at time of call in code, here, surely 30 for all your ajax requests.

Answer (score 2):

That's because in the first case the `alert()` is blocking and needs to be dismissed for the loop to continue.

In the second case (without alert), the ajax calls get executed immediately without waiting for the responses. i.e when the response for the first request `(i=1)` arrives, `i` is not necessarily `1`.

You can fix it by using `$.ajax` and its `context` option.

For example:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 30; i++) {     
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'get_sku_prices',
        data: {data: $('#product'+i).val()},
        context: {index: i}, // this value will be available in success as "this"
        success: function(result) {
            $('#price'+this.index).val(result); // use "this.index" here
            $('#adjustedprice'+this.index).val(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks techfoobar. this isn't working. I cant see any server response or post? Thanks for your time and knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Send Count to the server and try getting the count back on your result and do changes according to the count received from the result rather than the count from the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some delay in function execution

```
var i=0;
function postRequest(i){
$.post('get_sku_prices', {data: $('#product'+i).val()},function(result) {
    $('#price'+i).val(result);
    $('#adjustedprice'+i).val(result);
});
setTimeout(function(){
    postRequest(i++);
},1000);
}
```